# EDIT: Pyspark: drop rows based on another dataframe with conditions on many columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. I want to filter or drop rows on df1 based on  df2 column values

df2, I have to check like customername, product, year, qty and amount and then if df1 have all the values as same, I have to drop. (i.e) drop if customername = Gopi, product = ball, year = 2020, qty = 0 and amount <= 0.

Please let me know how to achieve, Thanks.

df1:

```
customername     product      year    qty     amount
Gopi             ball         2020    0       -100
Hana             ball         2020    2        200
Gopi             toy          2019    10       1000
Mesh             toy          2020    2        200
Tiby             ball         2017    1        100
Mona             pen          2020    1         70
Hana             ball         2019    2        200
Mona             ball         2020    1         70
Mona             toy          2020    1         70
Tiby             toy          2020    1        100
```

df2:

```
customername     product      year    qty     amount
Gopi             ball         2020    0       -100
Mona             pen          2020    1         70
```

Expected output:

```
customername     product      year    qty     amount
Hana             ball         2020    2        200
Gopi             toy          2019    10       1000
Mesh             toy          2020    2        200
Tiby             ball         2017    1        100
Hana             ball         2019    2        200
Mona             ball         2020    1         70
Mona             toy          2020    1         70
Tiby             toy          2020    1        100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to filter as below.

```
final_df = df1.join(df2, ((df1.customername == df2.customername) & (df1.product == df2.product) & (df1.year == df2.year) & (df1.qty == df2.qty) & (df1.amount <= 0), how='left_anti'))
```

Thanks.